# How do I Make the Correct Segue Link Between UITableViewController (Master) & UIViewController (Detail)?

Tags: swift, xcode6, segue

I want to connect a master VC with its detail VC via a dragged link.

I can successfully redo it with a virgin Master-Detail project generated in Xcode as seen below. 
 But I when I control-drag from the masterVC to the detailVC within my own project, I get only the Manual-Segue list generated.

The following is what I've done. 
 Dragging from Table View to blue detail yields the Manual Segue:
[image]

However doing the same with a previously-generated Master-Detail App yields the preferred connection:
[image]

---

Here's another perspective. 
 My **detail** VC's property is this:
[image]

But I want the properties to be this:
[image]

**Question:** What am I missing here?  
 How do I get the 'show', 'show detail', etc. Segue options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the *show* and *show detail* segue options by enabling size classes.  Turn on **Use Size Classes** in the *File Inspector* on the right side of Xcode:

[image]

---

You don't need to enable to size classes to do what you want though.  Simply choose the *push* segue type.  That is the equivalent of the new *show* if you're not using size classes.

Comment: Oh!  Okay... so the change is due to the 'size class' option.  I've tested your observation on an Apple boiler-plate Master/Detail project, toggling the 'size class' option and saw the link-option differences. 

BTW: I'm interested in the  'show detail' for the Master (table) vs Detail. 

Thanks.